# How to pass elements of an array as arguments without usage of asterisk

Tags: ruby

I have a method which returns two element arrays:

```
def method_from
   ....
   [value1, value2]
end
```

I need to send this array to another method, which also may take additional arguments:

```
def method_to(param1, param2, opts = {})
```

I want to have a simple interface:

```
obj2.method_to obj1.method_from
obj2.method_to obj1.method_from, option: 'value'
```

It's possible make it with additional asterisk:

```
obj2.method_to *obj1.method_from, option: value
```

but the code does not seem clean, because I need to know response structure of `method_from` to call `method_to`.

Is it possible to make an interface without using an asterisk for this case?

Comment: You don't need to "know the response structure of method_from", you just need to know to use an asterisk.  The method_from could return any number of things as long as it matches the number of arguments that method_to wants.  If you change that number, you don't need to change code that uses the asterisk.

Comment: Can you just put the arrays in an object, pass the object to the method, and extract the arrays where you need them?

Comment: @ChrisZimmerman i may do something like this through an array `def method_to(params, opts = {}); param1, param2 = params; ...`. But i'm not sure it is good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you observe "the code does not seem clean, because I need to know response structure of `method_from` to call `method_to`" you're sort of on the right track, but at the same time, you're also missing the bigger picture. You're trying to fit the output of one function to the inputs of another, and generally that means the two need to be compatible.

If `method_from` could emit some kind of object you can simply supply to `method_to` your problem is solved, you just pass it through. The trouble is these two methods were not designed to inter-operate that way.

This means you're stuck doing what you're doing with the asterisk, because after all what you want is a splat. The alternative is this even hackier solution:

```
def method_to(*args, **options)
  param1, param2 = args.flatten

  # Rest of code
end
```

Where that method can now take arguments of the form:

```
method_to(value1, value2, option: 'value')
```

Or the pass-through variant:

```
method_to([ value1, value2 ], option: 'value')
```